# Cannot compare to default-constructed rvalue

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I've got the following simple lambda:

```
auto end_current_token = [&] {
    if (current != Token()) {
        tokens.push_back(current);
        current = Token();
        cp = Codepoint();
    }
};
```

where `current` is of type `Token` and the operator is provided. But the compiler gives a strange error:

```
1>Lexer.cpp(6): error C2273: 'function-style cast' : illegal as right side of '->' operator
```

What's the problem with this?

Edit: Much as I wish to say that this isn't all the relevant code, it is. There's not one single use of -> in the whole program, except implicitly on `this`, and the error message points clearly to the lambda posted. However, since it is so small, I will post all the code.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
namespace Wide {
    class Lexer {
        struct Codepoint {
            Codepoint() {
                column = 0;
                line = 0;
                cp = 0;
            }
            int column;
            int line;
            wchar_t cp;
            bool operator==(wchar_t other) {
                return cp == other;
            }
        };
        enum TokenType {
            IDENTIFIER,
        };
        struct Token {
            Token()
                : line(0)
                , columnbegin(0)
                , columnend(0) {}
            Token(const Codepoint& cp) {
                *this = cp;
            }
            bool operator!=(const Token& other) {
                return !(line == other.line && columnbegin == other.columnbegin && columnend == other.columnend);
            }
            Token& operator+=(const Codepoint& cp) {
                if (cp.column >= columnend)
                    columnend = cp.column;
                if (columnbegin == 0)
                    columnbegin = cp.column;
                Codepoints += cp.cp;
                if (line == 0)
                    line = cp.line;
            }
            Token& operator=(const Codepoint& cp) {
                line = cp.line;
                columnbegin = cp.column;
                columnend = cp.column;
                Codepoints = cp.cp;
            }

            int line;
            int columnbegin;
            int columnend;
            TokenType type;
            std::wstring Codepoints;
        };
        struct FileStreamer {
            int current;
            std::vector<Codepoint> codepoints;
            int line;
            int column;
            std::wifstream file;
            FileStreamer(std::wstring filename)
            : file(filename, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary) {
                line = 0;
                column = 0;
                current = 0;
                // Extract all the codepoints immediately.
                Codepoint cp;
                while(*this >> cp)
                    codepoints.push_back(cp);
            }
            operator bool() {
                return current != codepoints.size();
            }
            FileStreamer& operator>>(Codepoint& cp) {
                if (*this) {
                    cp = codepoints[current];
                    current++;
                }
                return *this;
            }
            void putback() {
                if (current > 0)
                    current--;
            }
        };
        std::vector<Token> tokens;
        FileStreamer stream;
    public:
        Lexer(std::wstring file)
            : stream(file) {}
        void operator()();
    };
}
```

Implementation:

```
void Wide::Lexer::operator()() {
    Codepoint cp;
    Token current;
    auto end_current_token = [&] {
        if (current != Token()) {
            tokens.push_back(current);
            current = Token();
            cp = Codepoint();
        }
    };
    auto check = [&](wchar_t codepoint) -> bool {
        if (cp == codepoint) {
            end_current_token();
            tokens.push_back(cp);
            return true;
        }
        return true;
    };
    auto is_whitespace = [&](wchar_t codepoint) {
        return codepoint == L' ' || codepoint == L'\n' || codepoint == L'\t';
    };
    auto is_newline = [&](wchar_t codepoint) {
        return codepoint == L'\n';
    };
    while(stream >> cp) {
        // check for whitespace or comment first
        if (is_whitespace(cp.cp)) {
            end_current_token();
            continue;
        }

        if (cp == L'/') {
            end_current_token();
            Codepoint backup = cp;
            stream >> cp; // no need to check the stream for failure
            if (cp == L'/') {
                while(stream >> cp && !is_newline(cp.cp));
                continue;
            }
            // didn't find comment.
            tokens.push_back(backup);
            // put the other codepoint back
            stream.putback();
            continue;
        }
        if (check(L'.')) continue;
        if (check(L',')) continue;
        if (check(L'-')) continue;
        if (check(L';')) continue;
        if (check(L'*')) continue;
        if (check(L'&')) continue;
        if (check(L'^')) continue;
        if (check(L'%')) continue;
        if (check(L'"')) continue;
        if (check(L'!')) continue;
        if (check(L':')) continue;
        if (check(L'~')) continue;
        if (check(L'/')) continue;
        if (check(L'>')) continue;
        if (check(L'<')) continue;
        if (check(L'|')) continue;
        if (check(L')')) continue;
        if (check(L'(')) continue;
        if (check(L'[')) continue;
        if (check(L']')) continue;
        if (check(L'}')) continue;
        if (check(L'{')) continue;
        // Identifier/keyword

        current += cp;
    }
}
int main() {
    Wide::Lexer Input(L"Input.txt");
}
```

Barring pipework like a couple includes, that's it. That's the whole program.

Comment: I don't think you've posted all the relevant code. I don't see any `->` operator in this code.

Comment: Please post a minimal, **complete** program that demonstrates your problem. See http://sscce.org/.

Comment: Much as I'd like to say that that isn't the relevant code, it unfortunately is. The compiler error indicates the body of the lambda.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not know why the compiler is complaining about `operator->`, but I'm thinking it's either a compiler bug or `Token` is defined elsewhere.  Maybe the assignment is somehow being rearranged as a call through a function pointer.

In any case, I was able to get the code to compile by using explicit namespace scope resolution qualifiers.  Try this:

```
auto end_current_token = [&] {
        using namespace Wide;
    if (current != Wide::Lexer::Token()) {
        tokens.push_back(current);
        current = Wide::Lexer::Token();
        cp = Wide::Lexer::Codepoint();
    }
};
```

I believe -- but I'm not positive -- that this explicit resolution is needed anyway in the context of a lambda.

I'll do a little more research as to why you were having this problem.

Comment: If this sample failed to compile, I wouldn't have a problem.

Comment: Interesting. I'll give that a whack.

Comment: Don't know why I never came back and marked this as the answer- it did solve the problem, I think.